# file doesnt exist in search result

Tags: search

I have a document library with required fields.
Once I drag a file, the file is checked out since the required fields didn't filled up.
no matter what is the versioning definition in the document library settings, and although I re-index the library, I'm not getting the file in the search results.

what can be the reason?
Maybe its because that the file never checked in at least one time?

Comment: Your are correct, it works only after file checked in

Comment: I found the following url:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2304855. Its talking about draft and major versions... so Draft version can be found in the serach results?

Answer (score 2):

Head over to the document libraries settings and click the version settings. See the part about `Draft Item Security`.

If i can remember it right, enabling version settings enables the 2nd or 3rd option which stops the crawler account from indexing the files because the account does not have permissions to see them and add them to the search index.

To be able to index them you would like to set it to "Any users who can read items".

```
Who should see draft items in this picture library?  

 - Any user who can read items     
 - Only users who can edit items    
 - Only users who can approve items (and the author of the item)
```

Comment: The first option already checked. but still Im not getting the file. please note that the file is checked out from the time I drag it...

Comment: Did you imitate a recrawl on the library after you enabled the first option?

Comment: yes, I reindex the document library and I found that even If I define the document libray to create major and minor(draft) Items I set the security to the first Item...I need to first check in the file....then even If I save it as a draft Im getting the file.I just to be sure for 100% that the checked in is required stem in the flow....

Answer (score 1):

This is because until the initial check-in a document does not have ownership and will not be added to the crawl index.  When you add a document to SharePoint it first saves the document into the library.  Once the document is saved it then prompts you for the metadata and then checks in the document.  At this point, the document does not have any security assigned to it except that only you, the uploader, have security access to the file.  Because of this, SharePoint will not index the file.

Even if you allow all users to see draft versions it will not index files that do not have an initial check in.  Even if Check-ins are disabled SharePoint still does an initial check-in of a document.

To further illustrate this, if you go into the Library settings and click on **Manage files which have no checked in version** you will see a list of the files you did not set the required data on.  None of these files are fully checked in yet and will not be indexed.

Hope this explains things.